# Appending a charcter to a textbox In Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to append "|" Pipe symbol to a textbox on a button click. using this Method.

```
$scope.appendPipe = function(){
        var $textBox = $( '#synonyms' );
        $textBox.val($textBox.val()+'|');
        //textBox.value += ' |';
        textBox.focus();
 }
```

So right after a single character the pipe symbol is getting appended onto the textbox but when i am checking the value of the textbox using

> $scope.template.synonyms

I am not getting the pipe symbol.

Comment: Did you forget to un-comment the line of code that actually appends the pipe character?

Comment: Dont mix jquery and angularJS. Its a bad practice

Comment: Don't use jQuery for this. You're using Angular. Have a look at ngModel: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: Solution: use ngModel and remove anything related to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are mixing `jquery` and `AngularJS`. Don't mix it.

The changes you have done is not known to AngularJS if they are done by jQuery. Check `$digest` for reference. Use `ng-model` on textarea

```
<textarea ng-model="template.synonyms" ></textarea>
```

and then access it inside `controller`

```
$scope.appendPipe = function(){ 
   console.log($scope.template.synonyms);
   $scope.template.synonyms = $scope.template.synonyms+'|'
}
```

Comment: @AnmolKhandelwal : If it worked, mark it as an answer so that it can be helpful to others as well